# Migrating web application from .NET2 to .NET4

Tags: asp.net

I'm migrating a .NET2 web application to .NET4, in one of files I've `<%@ Register TagPrefix="FCKeditorV2" Namespace="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" Assembly="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" %>` and dll file is located into the bin folder, but when I run it it says:

> Could not load file or assembly 'FredCK.FCKeditorV2' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: right click your project, and add the reference, you ll have to add the reference by browsing to it.

Comment: ops! worked, write it as answer then I can mark it answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click your project, and add the reference, you ll have to add the reference by browsing to it in your projects bin.